# Linked text around circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, word-wrap

I have two links that are designed like this:

[image]

I’m trying to get my head around a decent solution for this. The text would preferably be PNG images, but text in an SVG would be acceptable as well. I also need a hover state, but that can be done by using a png sprite or text color, so that is not an issue. The biggest problem is to create proper click areas.

HTML/CSS is just somewhat square and limited when it comes to overlapping link/hover areas.

I peeked at SVG solutions, I also considered using multiple squares for "hotspots" or rotating letter by letter using CSS3.

Does anyone have a clever idea on how to solve this? IE9+ support would be nice.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, creating two circles with border-radius, and placing them using position

Comment: You could use [Lettering.JS](http://letteringjs.com) and some CSS transforms to position and rotate each letter around a circle.

Comment: is using a polygonal area map on a square image viable?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this simply as an svg with two textPaths, where each link is just an <a> tag. Click regions will be automatically computed.

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/text/text-path-linking.svg):

```
<svg 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 viewBox="700 0 500 500">
    <title>Simple example of using links with svg textPaths</title>
    <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
     text {
        font: 50px sans-serif; 
        text-anchor: middle;
     }
     a:hover { fill: cornflowerblue; }
    </style>
    <path id="p1" d="M700 400a200 200 0 1 1 400 0"/>
    <path id="p2" d="M700 400a200 200 0 1 1 400 0" transform="translate(0 50)"/>
  </defs>

  <text>
    <a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/first">
       <textPath xlink:href="#p1" startOffset="50%">First link</textPath>
    </a>
    <a xlink:href="http://www.example.com/second">
       <textPath xlink:href="#p2" startOffset="50%">Second link</textPath>
    </a>
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory.  What if you did something like this:

1. create a container with the text
2. create a duplicate on a higher z-index
3. create a solid white overlay with the exact dimensions for each.  (used later)
4. css rotate -90 on all

read this to skew the images opposite ways.

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

then skew the overlays to match up giving you the appearance of the bended example in your question.